# Zend_Form / MVC, where should form preparation and processing take place?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, forms

I currently have code in my controller which retrieves 3 types of entities from a db, in order to populate 3 select field.  The controller also takes responsibility for invoking the form objects validate method, and upon success, it instantiates and sets an entity's properties from the form inputs and calls on a data mapper to persist it.  I have a feeling that my controller is way too fat.  Any suggestions on where I should put my form preparation and processing code?  Should I move it into the form object?  Thx in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to put form processing in the form itself.  So I create a process() method in the form so then you can keep all of the form logic encapsulated in the form object.

For example in your controller:

```
$form = myForumClass();
...
$form.process();
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, thx for the response.  Does your form processing also take responsibility for setting properties on the related model(s) and persisting them?

Comment: Yes, that way the form is portable.  Makes it easy to make changes to a form that is loaded on multiple pages, knowing that all of the form logic is contained in that individual form class.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Using Zend_Form in Your Models](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models.html) by Matthew Weier O'Phinney. It explains how to move this kind of logic from your controller into the model.

Comment: Hey Vika, I appreciate your response.  I read that article you linked.  The thing that concerns me is that the author has model methods such as save().  I thought the general consensus was that models shouldn't have any idea of the means of persistence?

Answer (score 0):

For your database tables you should create models - these should contain the logic to get and set data into that table. So in this instance the model should be responsible for getting an array of values which is then passed to the controller and then to the form.

```
class MyModel 
{
    public function getSelectArray()
    {
        //Get stuff from Db here and format into an array ready to add to the form
    }
}
```

You can then do this in your controller

```
$model =  new MyModel();

$element->addMultiOptions($model->getSelectArray());
```

You could also create a specific form class which extends `Zend_Form`, this could then be called from any controller and return the same form - allowing you to reuse the form anywhere easily - e.g. you may want the same form on a registration page as on the My Profile page.

As an example, below is a function from a model of mine to do just this:

```
public function getSelectArray()
{
    $select = $this->select()->order(array("name ASC"));

    $categories = $select->query()->fetchAll();

    $return = array();

    foreach($categories as $category)
        $return[$category['id']] = $category['name'];

    return $return;
}
```